# Not printing all indices at indexPath.row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having an issue where eventsList has a number on indices, we'll use 27 as an example, and when I run the following code, the print (eventLatitudeString) and print (eventLongitudeString) lines print only a fraction of them, twice.  I'm a novice, so excuse the mess.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return eventsList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Agencies", ofType: "plist"),
        let agencyNameDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: String] {
        translatedAgencyName = agencyNameDict[eventsList[indexPath.row].agencyId!]
        }



    let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        // create dateFormatter with UTC time format
        utcDate = eventsList[indexPath.row].dateTime
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")! as TimeZone
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: utcDate!)

        // change to a readable time format and change to local time zone
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yy HH:mm"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "EST")! as TimeZone
        timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)

    cell.locationLabel.text = eventsList[indexPath.row].location
    cell.eventTimeLabel.text = timeStamp
    cell.eventTypeLabel.text = eventsList[indexPath.row].agencyEventTypeCode
    cell.agencyIdLabel.text = translatedAgencyName
    cell.eventTypeDescLabel.text = eventsList[indexPath.row].agencyEventTypeCodeDesc

    let numOfEvents = eventsList.count
    let stringNumOfEvents = "\(numOfEvents)"
    numberOfEvents.text = stringNumOfEvents

    eventLatitudeString = eventsList[indexPath.row].latitude!
    eventLongitudeString = eventsList[indexPath.row].longitude!

    print (eventLatitudeString)
    print (eventLongitudeString)
```

And if necessary, this is where items get appended to eventsList...

```
func fetchData(){

    print ("entered fetch")

    ref?.child("caddata").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let event =  Events()
            event.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)

            if event.originatingAction == "CadEventNew" {
                self.eventsList.insert(event, at: 0)

            } else if event.originatingAction == "CadFieldEvent" {
                self.eventsList.insert(event, at: 0)

            } else if event.originatingAction == "CadEmergencyEvent" {
                self.eventsList.insert(event, at: 0)

            } else if event.originatingAction == "CadCloseEvent" {
                self.cadPacketType = event.originatingAction
                self.cadEventNumber = event.agencyEventId
                self.queryCloseUIDFromDB()

            } else {
              //  print ("The End")
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.myTableView.reloadData()
            }

        }
})

}
```

Comment: Show your `numberOfRowsInSection` method in your question.

Comment: numberOfRows has been added to top of code shown

Comment: also please show your numberOfSections code?

Comment: `cellForRowAt` is only called for the number of visible cells so if you don't scroll it's called only a few times. By the way: **Do not** read from a file in the bundle in `cellForRowAt`. The method is called frequently and getting the same data again and again is unnecessarily expensive.

Comment: @vadian i think that’s my problem. So being very very new at this, let me ask, where should I put that code?

Comment: @vadian If you can make your comment an answer, ill mark it correct

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    print("number of sections numberOfSections : \(tableView)")
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("numberOfRowsInSections tableView : \(tableView)")
    return eventsList.count
}
```

Also please check all your index path get called, jus by printing indexPath, Remember one thing.  **cellForRowAt indexPath** will call only at time of cell display. if cell is outside visible content of tableview scroll, this method will not call.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   print("IndexPath - Section:\(indexPath.section) row:\(indexPath.row)")

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Agencies", ofType: "plist"),
      let agencyNameDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: String] {

     .........................
```

Comment: That prints IndexPath - Section:0 row:0 to IndexPath - Section:0 row:12 TWICE while eventsList.count is 16

Comment: `numberOfSections` defaults to 1 if it is not implemented in data source